# capture ran reports without the report server

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, reporting-services, reportserver

I am trying to establish a way of capturing data (such as run time, parameters passed, username, etc.) from our reports on SSRS without using the reportserver database. Unfortunately we are not able to query against this database at every site we run our reports.

Is there a way of capturing this data from when the reports when they are ran (i.e from the XML files), and  writing this to a stored procedure, which produces a table that stores all this data? I know that you can get a summary of all the data through the XML file, but I don't know if this would be the best way of gong about it.

Comment: Security access to run queries against the reportserver database. At some sites this requires admins access, which we do not have.

Comment: No the sites aren't linked and yes we do have SSMS at all sites.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the XML files"?